# Кириллица в коде на Common Lisp

Tags: кириллица, lisp, emacs, common-lisp

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли называть функции или ещё какие-либо элементы в тексте программы на Common Lisp по-русски? Интересует Emacs + SLIME.

Comment: @Merlin, а что  мешает самому попробовать?

Не знаю насчет CommonLisp, а в родном Emacs-овком (в буфере \*scratch\*)

    (setq z 55)
    55
    (+ z 5)
    60
    z
    55
    (setq я 50)
    50
    (+ я 55)
    105
    я
    50

все получается.

Comment: да я пробовал? но ничего не происходит, нажимаешь Enter пишет - No value, хотя если назвать по английский все считает
![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/9aMVf1X.png

Comment: А в \*scratch\* как дела?

У меня (сейчас под рукой) один `GNU Emacs 23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600)` в винде, другой `GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.10)` в xubuntu.

А Common-lisp в Emacs надо специально ставить? У меня похоже (по чтению вывода Ctl-h a) ничего (кроме common-lisp-mode) нет.

Comment: @avp пользовался  lispbox там из коробки все поставлено.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После долгих поисков нашёл всё-таки решение.

Я скачивал для себя версию lispbox-0.7-ccl-1.6-windowsx86.zip с официального сайта lispbox. Для включения поддержки русского языка, необходимо выполнить всего 2 действия:

**Действие 1:**

Найти в директории lispbox-0.7 файл lispbox.bat, и там найти следующую строку:

```
set TO_EVAL="(progn (load \"lispbox\") (slime))"
```

Её необходимо заменить на:

```
set TO_EVAL="(progn (setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix) (load \"lispbox\") (slime))"
```

**Действие 2:**

Найти в директории lispbox-0.7 в поддиректории slime-* файл swank-loader.lisp. В начало файла добавить следующую строку:

```
(setf CCL:*DEFAULT-EXTERNAL-FORMAT* :utf-8)
```

Теперь редактор будет корректно загружать и отображать исходники с русским текстом, в кодировке UTF-8.